# How can i retrieve css path of a webelement through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a list of elements (`find_elements_by_css_selector`), and now I need to get their css locators. I tried something like:

```
foo.get_property('css_selector')
```

but it returns `None`.

Comment: use a for loop and apply this on every element in the loop.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The CSS class selector matches elements based on the contents of their class attribute.Can you please post html here?

Comment: is "css_selector" a valid property of a WebElement?  I'm not familiar with it.  You used a css_selector to find the element in the first place, is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You state that you work with python Selenium and you use the find_by_css method to get a list of webElements and you need to get their "css_locator" property. That's not a standard css property, so unless someone declared it, trying to get it  would result in a None value if that property doesnt exist. You can see the properties of your element if you open your website in a browser like Chrome or Firefox, Inspect the element and navigate to the Properties section.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what exactly you meant by *get css path* from webelement.

As you are having a list of elements obtained through `find_elements_by_css_selector()`, possibly you are looking for the **CSS property** of each *WebElement* and to extract any of the property you can use the following solution:

```
foo.value_of_css_property("property_name")
```

Comment: I actually think the OP needs the css locator string for one of his elements, like you get from tools that compute them for you, such as Chrome's Inspect > Copy Selector function. In lack of a clarification from OP I'm afraid this question does not have an answer.

Comment: @BoboDarph Initially I thought that too. Then saw OP already used `find_elements_by_css_selector()` so s/he is done with _selector_ part. Now combining **element**, **get_property** and **css** the only exciting thing is **`CSS property`**. Additionally, OP seems a new contributor, so there can be come confusion in constructing the exact question